# Странное поведение при сравнении строк в Си

Tags: c, gcc

Добрый день, использую *gnu-gcc compiler* и он ведет себя странно со строками то-есть он просто **не проверяет строки которые были присвоены через `scanf`** вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char *command;
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s\n", &command);
    if (command == "qewr") {
       printf("programm");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Однако так работает

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char *command;
    printf("> ");
    command = "qewr";
    if (command == "qewr") {
       printf("programm");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ой-е-ей...

```
char *command;
scanf("%s\n", &command);
```

Итак, у вас выделено место для переменной `command` размером для указателя (обычно, в 32-разрадной программе, 4 байта). `scanf` получает адрес этого места, и пишет туда.  Если он пишет туда больше 4 байт - уже получается выход за границы массива!

Еще - `scanf("%s"`читает *одно слово* - вам нужно именно это?

А дальше вы пытаетесь трактовать этот кусок строки как указатель.
Просто ужас.

Почему не работает сравнение, вам написал @gbg.

Я бы действовал примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char command[128];
    printf("> ");
    fgets(command,128,stdin);
    int lastSymbol = strlen(command)-1;
    if (command[lastSymbol] == '\n')
        command[lastSymbol] = 0;

    if (strcmp(command,"qewr") == 0)
    {
       printf("programm\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только strlen несколько раз лучше не считать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Готов спорить, что умный оптимизатор это оптимизирует... но вы правы, перепишу. P.S. Проверил. VC++ 2015 оптимизировал.

Comment: Умный оптимизатор еще принты заменить может на путс

Comment: @bukkojot Нет, нельзя - `puts` добавляет `\n`... :)

Comment: Нет, порой можно. Можно посмотреть на дизасмы, как работают компиляторы и их оптимизаторы: https://beginners.re/RE4B-RU.pdf

Comment: @bukkojot Но не в данном случае - здесь в `printf` нет `\n`.

Comment: Да, но я говорил в общем случае о оптимизации. Прошу прощения, если ввел в заблуждение.

Answer (score 3):

Красиво вы себя посадили в воронку - без 500 мл известного напитка не разберешься!

Так вот, проблема в том, что вы сравниваете указатели на строки, а не содержимое этих строк.

В первом случае, у вас указатели разные - буфер, куда записала `scanf` и буфер, который сформировал компилятор.

Во втором случае, вы сравниваете буфер, который сформировал компилятор, с буфером, который сформировал компилятор.

Дальше в дело вступает оптимизатор, который не позволяет затолкать в программу две идентичные строки и убирает дубль. Таким образом, вы сравниваете буфер с самим собой.

Правильное сравнение строк делает `strcmp()`

Ну и мелкие проблемы, вроде того, что память для `scanf` нужно выделить явным образом.

Comment: Там бы ещё память под буфер иметь...

Comment: А что со слешем?

Comment: @Duoxx со слэшем уже я ошибся